# how to disable fast frames in ath5k wireless driver

Tags: c, networking, macros, driver, wireless

By default, fast frames are enabled in ath5k. (http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath5k)
I have found the macro which disables it

```
#define AR5K_EEPROM_FF_DIS(_v)      (((_v) >> 2) & 0x1
```

The question is what do I do with it?
Do I replace the above line with

```
#define AR5K_EEPROM_FF_DIS(_v)  1
```

?

Do I compile it passing some parameter?

The bit-shift expression confuses me. Is `_v` a variable?

The question is more general as to how to deal with such macros in drivers. I've seen them in other codes too and always got confused.

Comment: Its not a regular expression, its a bit-shift

Comment: You are right, it was a speed error.
My confusion remains though.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but this seems a rather ambitious task for someone who is just starting to learn C.  You might be better off starting with a C book, working through its exercises.  If you don't really want to learn C but do want to hack around with existing linux modules, you could try asking a question on the linux wireless mailing list.  I'm not sure they'll be particularly tolerant of beginner level questions but you can always try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I try to explain with a simplified example

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Just for print in binary mode */
char *chartobin(unsigned char c)
{
    static char a[9];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
          a[7 - i] = (c & (1 << i)) == (1 << i) ? '1' : '0';
    a[8] = '\0';
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char u = 0xf;

    printf("%s\n", chartobin(u)); 
    u >>= 2; // Shift bits 2 positions (to the right)
    printf("%s\n", chartobin(u));       
    printf("%s\n", chartobin(u & 0x1)); // Check if the last bit is on

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00001111
00000011
00000001
```

Do I replace the above line with `#define AR5K_EEPROM_FF_DIS(_v)  1`?

Nooooo!!

If you initialize `u` with `0xb` instead of `0xf` you get:

```
00001011
00000010
00000000
```

As you can see `(((_v) >> 2) & 0x1 != 1`

Answer (score 0):

Fast frames are not enabled or used on ath5k. It's a feature allowing the card to send multiple frames at once (think of it as an early version of 11n [frame aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_aggregation)) that's implemented on MadWiFi and their proprietary drivers and can only be used with an Access Point that also supports it. What you see there is a flag stored at the device's EEPROM that instructs the driver if fast frames can be used or not, that macro you refer to just checks if that flag is set. You can modify the header file to always return 1 but that wouldn't make any difference, the driver never uses that information.